# JQuery Element Hieght not the same on reality

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable.js and i try to limit its height, on a specific row number like 4.5 rows, but i have a probleme on row height ( tr height ) for exempel i get 5 rows using this method with maxDisplayedRow = 5 :

```
function getRows(maxDisplayedRow) {
    return $("#productDesignedFor-table tbody tr:lt("+maxDisplayedRow+")").toArray();
}
```

and im trying to calculate it with :

with rows = getRows() method
and maxRows = 5

if there are 5 rows on table i reduce it to calculate 4.5 of all height of the rows

```
function getTableHeightWithLastRowIsHalf(rows, maxRows) {

return tableHeight = rows.length === maxRows
            ? rows.reduce(function(acc, row, i) {
                console.log(row.scrollHeight)
                console.log({row: row})
                const rowHeight = $(row).height();
                return i !== maxRows - 1
                    ? acc + rowHeight 
                    : acc + rowHeight/2;
            }, 0)
            : false;
}
```

i call this methode on settings :

```
initComplete: () => {
const maxDisplayedRow = getMaxDisplayedRow(); // = 5
const rows = getRows(maxDisplayedRow) // all rows less than 5 = [row].length < 5

$('.dataTables_scrollBody').css("max-height", getTableHeightWithLastRowIsHalf(rows, maxDisplayedRow));
}
```

all of those functions are on $(document).ready()

the probleme is :

when i console log `console.log($(row).height())` it gives me : 59

but the `console.log($(row))` has 79

even with `row.scrollHeight` `row.clientHeight`

i tried setTimeOut on the function juste in case all css and html applied but no result.

the question is:

why the same object gives diffrent result because that cause calculation problem ?

Answer (score 0):

i found it, it was the scroll added after applying height, some columns take a new height depending on the text that goes to next line.